# How to create a Dynamic IEnumerable

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

I know this is a simple question for you. But I am a beginner in c#. 
What I want to achieve is to create a method that will store any type of List of Objects from my Model. e.g `List<Person>`.

I have tried to make something like this..

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetObjects<T>()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);

    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo item in properties)
    {
        // store properties
    }


    List<T> objects = new List<T>();

    using (SqlConnection str = GetSqlConnection)
    {
        // retrieve data from db 
        //then store it to list of objects
    }

    return objects;

}
```

This will enable me to retrieve data using only this method.

EDIT:

I already manage to create this sample code to retrieve a specific table from a database.

```
public IEnumerable<ItemBrand> getAllBrand
{
    get
    {
        List<ItemBrand> brands = new List<ItemBrand>();

        using (MySqlConnection strConn = getMySqlConnection())
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM tblbrand";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, strConn);

            strConn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rd.Read())
            {
                ItemBrand brand = new ItemBrand();

                brand.brandID = Convert.ToInt32(rd["brandID"]);
                brand.Name = rd["brandName"].ToString();

                brands.Add(brand);
            }

            return brands;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I have multiple methods of this in my solution. I would love to remove those duplicate codes with your help.

Comment: What is the question here? Clearly you have already managed to create a `List<T>`, is the question how to construct an instance of `T` from a row from the database?

Comment: What is your actual question? You can create a list of object (`List<object>`).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you for your response. Yes retrieve all rows from a table then store it in my List<T>

Comment: Please clarify what your actual question is. Do you know how to retrieve rows from a statement executed in the database? Do you know how to construct an instance of  `T`? Do you know how to assign property values to an instance through reflection?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I already updated my question. thanks

Comment: I think it is a bad idea. Rather use an ORM such as Linq2SQL or Entity framework if you want less code in your functions. But you should have one function for each type.

Comment: @Magnus Could you please elaborate why it is a bad idea. I was trying to eliminate duplicate codes. thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
<code> 
  // Create a new type of the entity I want
Type t = typeof(T);

T returnObject = new T();

for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++) {
    string colName = string.Empty;
    colName = dataReader.GetName(i);
    // Look for the object's property with the columns name, ignore case
    PropertyInfo pInfo = t.GetProperty(colName.ToLower(), BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // did we find the property ?
    if (pInfo != null) {
        if (dataReader.Read()) {
            object val = dataReader[colName];
            // is this a Nullable<> type
            bool IsNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pInfo.PropertyType) != null);
            if (IsNullable) {
                if (val is System.DBNull) {
                    val = null;
                } else {
                    // Convert the db type into the T we have in our Nullable<T> type
                    val = Convert.ChangeType(val, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pInfo.PropertyType));
                }
            } else {
                // Convert the db type into the type of the property in our entity
                val = Convert.ChangeType(val, pInfo.PropertyType);
            }
            // Set the value of the property with the value from the db
            pInfo.SetValue(returnObject, val, null);
        }
    }
}

</code>
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try and refactor this snippet you gave, see if it works

Comment: Okey. let me know if you have any problem. i also have complete code to select  list from database if you will need.

Comment: one more thing you need to remember if you want to use generic function like this column name and entity name should be same. only when this method will work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a generic method like:

```
public IEnumerable<T> CreateListOfItems(string tableName,
                                        Func<MySqlDataReader, T> itemCreator)
{
    var items = new List<T>();

    using (var strConn = getMySqlConnection())
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, strConn);

        strConn.Open();
        var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rd.Read())
        {
            items.Add(itemCreator(rd));
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Then use like this:

```
private ItemBrand CreateItemBrandFromDBData(MySqlDataReader rd)
{
    return new ItemBrand
    {
        BrandID = Convert.ToInt32(rd["brandID"]),
        Name = rd["brandName"].ToString()
    };
}

...

var brands = CreateListOfItems<ItemBrand>(tblbrand, CreateItemBrandFromDBData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a method that gets the result retrieved from a stored proc and transformes it into a list of objects.
The only thing you need to pay attention to is:
The class you are mapping to must have the same column names as the ones that are sent from the database.

```
public IEnumerable <T> ExecuteReaderToList<T>(string storedProcedure, IDictionary parameters = null,
              string connectionString = null)
        {
            ICollection list = new List();
```

`var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();           

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                }
            }

            cmd.Connection = conn;

            conn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var element = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

                    foreach (var f in properties)
                    {
                        var o = reader[f.Name];
                        if (o.GetType() != typeof(DBNull))
                        {
                            f.SetValue(element, o, null);
                        }

                        o = null;
                    }

                    list.Add(element);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return list;
    }`